# Insert row and autofill locked cells

Tags: excel, protected

I have a table in Excel 2007 where certain columns have formulas that are automatically filled downwards into their respective new cells when I insert a new row.

To prevent other users from modifying these columns, I locked them by protecting the sheet.

However, protecting the sheet prevents the formulae from copying down when inserting a new row with the following error:

> The cell or chart that you are trying to change is protected and
>   therefore read-only. To modify a protected cell or chart, first remove
>   protection using the Unprotect Sheet (Review tab, Changes group). You
>   may be prompted for a password.

Is it possible to have both features together:

- Insert a new row and automatically copy the formulas down
- Protect the columns that contains formulas

Comment: I didn't find a way to do this simply. You will probably have to use VBA.

Comment: JMax is right, you will have to use vba to accomplish this.

Comment: You can protect the specific column only in the table hope this link will help you http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/cells/protect2013.php